# Weird R formatting in Vim

Tags: r, vim

When using the `magrittr` package, having a code block that starts and ends on the same level of indentation results in vim formatting all subsequent lines one indent too far.

How do I stop this behavior?

Current:

```
tmp <- function(x) {
        what <- hey %>% 
        {
                5
        }

                yikes
}
```

Desired:

```
tmp <- function(x) {
        what <- hey %>% 
        {
                5
        }

        yay
}
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [Vi and Vim Beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), the SE community for `vi` and `vim` users.

Comment: @RuiBarradas You're right.

Comment: Not really sure how to move questions, so the link to the vim SE on is here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/prevent-weird-r-formatting-after-curly-braces-on-the-same-level